# How to style Formik fields based on error and touched state

Tags: reactjs, styles, formik

I have a question about rendering errors when using Formik@1.5.7 to create forms in React.

I am trying to figure out how to properly render different styles for my input based on whether or not the input has been touched and has errors.

```
 {({ values, error, touched }) => (
        <Form>
          <Field name="Lawn" type="text">
            {({ field, form }) => (
              <Input
                style={form.touched.Lawn && form.errors.Lawn ? 
                                   { style } : { styleError }}
                {...field}
                type="text"
                placeholder="Lawn Details"
              />
            )}
          </Field>

const style = {
  margin: '1em 0em',
  fontSize: '1.5em',
  backgroundColor: 'white',
};

const styleError = {
  margin: '1em 10em',
  fontSize: '1.5em',
};
```

I believe my error has to do with not properly accessing the touched and error states in the form.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You're close, you just incorrectly passed `style` and `styleError`. They should not be surrounded with braces (and they're also backwards because the error formatting will show when there is no error and vice versa).

```
<Input
    style={form.touched.Lawn && form.errors.Lawn ? styleError : style}
    {...field}
    type="text"
    placeholder="Lawn Details"
/>
```

Here's a [full example](https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-wilson-8p56f).

Comment: would the form.touched.Lawn part change if Lawn was part of a FieldArray?

Comment: I tried using                                                                                                            
       style={form.touched[field.name] && form.errors[field.name] ? styleError : style} but that did not work. I was using name="RequestForm[0].LawnDetails" and tried just using that as the name, but it cause an error because of the lodash.

Comment: You should use Formik's `getIn()` function for that e.g. `getIn(form.errors, field.name)`.